# Entity Framework Core Nested List Performance

Tags: c#, .net, database, entity-framework

I struggle with the entity framework core performance while I try to add an additional item to a nested list.

Let's say as an example:
I have multiple projects, the project contains multiple houses, the house has multiple facades and the facade has multiple windows.
If I now want to add an additional window to a specific project, house, facade I do it like that:

```
    public async Task SaveWindowAsync(Guid projectId, Guid houseId, Guid facadeId, WindowEntity windowEntity)
    {
        using (ProjectsDbContext context = new ProjectsDbContext())
        {
            var windowList = context.ProjectSet
                .Include(p => p.Houses)
                .ThenInclude(h => h.Facades)
                .ThenInclude(f => f.Windows)
                .First(p => p.Id == projectId).Houses
                .First(h => h.Id == houseId).Facades
                .First(f => f.Id == facadeId).Windows;

            windowList.Add(windowEntity);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

This works fine regarding the functionality. However the performance gets slower and slower when the database is increasing. Is there a more performant way to add an item to a nested list?

**Update 1**

I created a simple test database with this futuristic objects with 50 projects, each project has 10 houses, each house has 10 facades and each facade has 10 windows. this results in a database size of about 10Mb.

In the test I add 1000 Windows after each other (no bulk):

The solution mention above requires a total time of 145s.

The solution mentioned by @David Browne - Microsoft takes about 54s

```
var facadeEntity = context.Set<FacadeEntity>()
    .Include(f => f.Windows)
    .Single(f => f.Id == facadeId);

facadeEntity.Windows.Add(windowEntity);

await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

**Update 2**

As recommended by @David Browne I added a ForeignKey to the window:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<FacadeEntity>()
.HasMany(f => f.Windows).WithOne()
.HasForeignKey(f => f.FacadeId)
.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

The save is executed like that:

```
context.Entry(windowEntity).Property(nameof(WindowEntity.FacadeId)).CurrentValue = facadeId;
context.Set<WindowEntity>().Add(windowEntity);
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

This issue is the same the more windows I have the longer the add takes.
The durartion for 1000 Windows is around 53s.

Comment: Can you please check how the query is formed? Instead of `Include`, you can write the query based on `Join` to fetch facade and add the window in child object.

Comment: That first `First` is going to pull back the first project and all the houses, facades, and windows for it.  Instead use a combination of `Where` and `SelectMany` to filter and then take the first.

Comment: @juharr you mean like:   var windowList = context.ProjectSet.Where(p => p.Id == projectId).SelectMany(p => p.Houses).Where(h => h.Id == facadeId).SelectMany(f => f.Facades).Where(f => f.Id == facadeId).SelectMany(w => w.Windows).ToList();
                    .Where(f => f.Id == facadeId).SelectMany(w => w.Windows).ToList();

Answer (score 2):

> I currently have only a "DbSet ProjectSet" you would add an additional DbSet to the context?

If you don't have declared `DbSet<T>` for an entity, access it through [`DbContext.Set<T>()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0#System_Data_Entity_DbContext_Set__1), something like:

```
public static async Task SaveWindowAsync(Guid projectId, Guid houseId, Guid facadeId, Window windowEntity)
{
    using (ProjectsDbContext context = new ProjectsDbContext())
    {
        var facade = context.Set<Facade>()
                            .Where(f => f.FacadeId == facadeId)
                            .Single();

        facade.Windows.Add(windowEntity);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

This translates to:

```
SELECT TOP(2) [f].[FacadeId], [f].[HouseId]
FROM [Facade] AS [f]
WHERE [f].[FacadeId] = @__facadeId_0
```

and then:

```
INSERT INTO [Window] ([WindowId], [FacadeId])
VALUES (@p0, @p1)
```

Assuming `Facade` has a single-column primary key.  If it has a compound key of (ProjectId,HouseId,FacadeId), then add those to the `Where`.

The best way to do this, however is to set the Foreign Key property of Window.FacadeId and not load the Facade at all.  In EF Core you can do this with Shadow Properties if you don't have a Foreign Key Property.  EG:

```
public static async Task SaveWindowAsync(Guid projectId, Guid houseId, Guid facadeId, Window windowEntity)
{
    using (ProjectsDbContext context = new ProjectsDbContext())
    {
        context.Entry(windowEntity).Property("FacadeId").CurrentValue = facadeId;
        context.Set<Window>().Add(windowEntity);

        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: this is much faster but still it takes longer when there are more windows in the facade list. Is it possible to avoid loading the whole facade list?

Comment: That code will load a single Facade, then insert a single Window (see update to answer).  Why do you say "it takes longer when there are more windows in the facade list"?

Comment: I have a unit test which adds 10' 000 windows to a facade and every times logs the duration of the addWindow call. The total duration is about 3000s, the first addWindow call takes about 0.7s once it is jitted it takes around 0.2s then the duration increases as longer as it goes. the 10'000 window add takes about 1s. With this code the facade is loaded with all windows containing in the list.

Comment: Does the test use a single DbContext?  If so the change tracker has to track all those objects.

Comment: What do you mean exactly? I call 10'000  SaveWindowAsync(..) so it is always a new instance of the project db context.

Comment: Ok, I see. Do you have Lazy Loading enabled?  Instead of adding the Window to the Facade.Windows navigation property, just set the Window's FacadeID shadow property. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/shadow-properties.  That way you don't even have to load the Facade entity.

Comment: As far as I know lazy loading is not yet implemented in entitiy framework core or do I miss something? I can give this a try but the issue is that there are already a lot of databases where this shadow property is not existing therefore I hoped for an easier way.

Comment: With EF Core you should have either a Shadow Property or a Foreign Key Property.  And I can't get the loading behavior you describe to repro without Lazy Loading in EF Core 2.2 or 3.0.

Comment: I think the shadow property is the way to go. I am not aware that ef core supports lazy loading without "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Proxies" and I don't use this package.

Comment: Se my update 2 even with the foreign key it takes the same amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to *add* a Window to a specific project/house/facade, can you just set the FacadeId on the WindowEntity directly and save that? Presumably, the Window has a FacadeId property, just as Facade has a HouseId, and House has a ProjectId. If Window has the Ids of all its parents (unnecessary), then just set the House and Project Ids as well.

```
public async Task SaveWindowAsync(Guid projectId, Guid houseId, Guid facadeId, WindowEntity windowEntity)
{
    using (ProjectsDbContext context = new ProjectsDbContext())
    {            
        windowEntity.FacadeId = facadeId;
        context.WindowSet.Add(windowEntity);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

**Update:**
If you don't want to set the facadeId on the entity directly, then you can load *just* the facade, and set its Facade property rather than the Id. You can optionally add the windowEntity to the Facade's Windows collection as well if you are going to continue working with that instance of the collection.

```
public async Task SaveWindowAsync(Guid facadeId, WindowEntity windowEntity)
{
    using (ProjectsDbContext context = new ProjectsDbContext())
    {
        var facade = Facades.Single(x => x.Id == facadeId);
        windowEntity.Facade = facade;
        facade.Windows.Add(windowEntity);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't like that the child has the id of the "parent" directly so therefore setting the parent id was not an option so far.

Comment: You could still skip all that navigation, load up the facade directly, and add the window straight to that. You obviously know the FacadeId since you're using it in the example query. You can still skip navigating through the project and house to get there. See updated answer above:

Comment: Yes I know the facade Id but currently the window does not contain the facade id or the facade. Only the facade knows the corresponding windows.

Answer (score 0):

You should firstly select from your Windows DbSet then join Facades then join houses
 your query should looks like that

```
 var windowList = context.DbSet<Windows>().Where(w => w.Facade.Id== facadeId && w.Facade.House.Id == houseId && w.Facade.House.Project.Id == projectId)
```

Comment: I currently have only a "DbSet<ProjectEntity> ProjectSet" you would add an additional DbSet to the context?

Comment: Exactly, it should not change your database structure,  but in your code you could add this entity even without selection as wrote Mel.

Comment: This would mean that I require on each object an Id of the "parent" object so far I don't have that.

Comment: You can add it,than your performance should increase.It also does not change database schema.

Comment: Then I would have to handle all the databases which already exist.

Comment: Ideally your code properties should match with database schema.I recommend read entity framework tutorials   https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-dbcontext.aspx
https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/configure-one-to-many-relationship-using-fluent-api-in-ef-core.aspx